# Problema con printf en C

Tags: c, printf

Ayuda a un novato total. Tengo un problema, ya que se "solapa" la salida del siguiente código en C. Pongo abajo ejemplo de salida.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    char sCol;
    int sRow;
    char DESTcol;
    int DESTrow;

    printf("INPUT\n");
    printf("SOURCE COL?\n");
    scanf("%c", &sCol);
    
    printf("SOURCE ROW?\n");
    scanf("%d", &sRow);

    printf("DEST COL?\n"); //falla
    scanf("%c", &DESTcol);
    
    printf("DEST ROW?\n");
    scanf("%d", &DESTrow);
    
    printf("OUTPUT\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Obteniendo la siguiente salida:

```
INPUT
SOURCE COL?
f
SOURCE ROW?
2
DEST COL?
DEST ROW? //en este solapamiento está el fallo que no encuentro
3
OUTPUT
```

Gracias de antemano, no sé qué me puede fallar. No entiendo por qué se solapa y no funciona el scanf de &DESTcol.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando terminas de introducir un campo presionas la tecla `enter` para continuar.

Cuando haces lecturas con `scanf`, la función lee el dato pedido hasta que encuentra un separador (salto de línea, tabulador, espacio, ...). Cuando esto pasa, deja el separador en el buffer de entrada y termina. La siguiente ejecución de `scanf` verá, en primer lugar, el separador, por lo que procederá a eliminarlo y entonces empezará a leer el siguiente dato.

Este es el comportamiento por defecto, que afecta a todas las llamadas de `scanf` menos, en principio, a una, y es la que lee caracteres. Esta llamada **no elimina el separador**. En este caso tendrás que eliminarlo expresamente.

Eliminar el separador es tan sencillo como dejar un espacio antes del %

```
scanf(" %c", &DESTcol);
```

También podrías descartar el separador leyendo un caracter del buffer de entrada:

```
getchar();
scanf("%c", &DESTcol);
```

¿Por qué sucede esto?

El motivo es que cuando quieres leer, por ejemplo, un entero, queda claro que los separadores no van a formar parte del dato a leer, así que se pueden descartar con seguridad. Sin embargo, a la hora de leer un único caracter ... ¿Cómo sabe `scanf` cuándo te interesa leer el separador y cuándo no? Para simplificar, se tomó la decisión de leer lo que hubiese en el buffer sin importar si era separador o no. Dejando al programador la responsabilidad de eliminar el separador en este caso.